# Link not working onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have a bookmarklet which a user can add to their browser, simple code:

```
javascript:(function(){ListIt=document.createElement('script');ListIt.src='http://***.com/js/list_it/feed.js';document.body.appendChild(ListIt);})();void(0);
```

I also want to have a button which a user can add to their own site and so want to do the same as above but onclick, but what I'm trying simply does nothing

Here's what I'm trying:

```
<a href="#" onclick="(javascript:(function(){ListIt=document.createElement('script');ListIt.src='http://***.com/js/list_it/feed.js';document.body.appendChild(ListIt);})();void(0);)"><img src="http://***.com/images_/icons/list-it-button.png" border="0" title="List It!"></a>
```

Comment: get rid of the javascript: in the onclick, the label is useless there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="#" onclick="(function(){var ListIt=document.createElement('script');ListIt.src='http://example.com/js/list_it/feed.js';document.body.appendChild(ListIt);}())' return false;"><img src="http://example.com/images_/icons/list-it-button.png" border="0" title="List It!"></a>​
```

Answer (score 1):

Two thing I noticed about your code are:

First:

In this section: `href="#" onclick="(javascript:(` you missed that `"javascript:"` is a protocol detected by the browser to execute JavaScript code.  It should be used in the URL values such as the value of the `href` attribute, not the `onclick` event. On the other hand, you can simply remove the `javascript:` from the `onclick` event and everything will work fine.

Second:

`javascript:` is like `http:` or `https:` and it can't start with parentheses like `(javascript:(`.

You should use this:

```
<a href="javascript:((function(){ListIt=document.createElement('script');ListIt.src='http://***.com/js/list_it/feed.js';document.body.appendChild(ListIt);})();void(0);)">
    <img src="http://***.com/images_/icons/list-it-button.png" border="0" title="List It!">
</a>
```

Comment: Please don't roll back helpful edits and destroy good information in your answer. Your latest edit removed the sample code at the end here, harming this answer, so I brought it back to a useful state. I've done the same for your other answers.

Comment: Thank you. It's a long story why I did that. ;)